# JGraph in an eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, swt, jgraph

does anyone knows whether I can use JGraph in an eclipse plugin to draw some graphs? I read about that JGraph is for Swing and Eclipse plugins are in SWT, is there a problem?

Cheers,
Simon

Comment: Does JGraph offer any feature that the graph libraries for SWT don't?

Comment: Have you checked Eclipse GEF?

Comment: Or just [Zest](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/zest/index.php)?

Comment: Currently I use Zest, but I wanted to find out, whether I can use another graph api like JGraph.

Comment: @jsimon Why? Does JGraph have any features that Zest of GEF don't?

Comment: @Baz this is not the point. I need to find the possibilities to draw a graph in an eclipse plugin.

Comment: @jsimon And you can do that with Zest of GEF. If you need JGraph, look at my answer below. If that's not a option, then you can't use JGraph, because it does not natively support SWT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use Swing components in an SWT application.
If JGraph works perfectly remains to be tested though, I couldn't find any positive results on google.

[Here](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Swing-SWT-Integration/index.html) is an article from Eclipse on how to use Swing components.

Good luck.